# Attempting to drop a column yields ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of .... (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, ddl

I am trying to run an alter table command to drop a column:

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of .... (errno: 150).
```

If I understand correctly it is a foreign key problem, but I do not have a clue how to fix it. Would somebody be so kind and tell me how to get it working.

The code used for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
cid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
assets_id INT NOT NULL,
cat_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
INDEX(assets_id),
FOREIGN KEY (assets_id) REFERENCES asset(aid) ON UPDATE CASCADE

)
ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE categories DROP COLUMN assets_id;
```

The table categories is completely blank. So there is no information to set off the CASCADE restrictions.

How can I delete the column assets_id?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE categories` to show the name of constraint.

Most probably it will be `categories_ibfk_1`

Use the name to drop the foreign key first and the column then:

```
ALTER TABLE categories DROP FOREIGN KEY categories_ibfk_1;
ALTER TABLE categories DROP COLUMN assets_id;
```

Comment: @Henkka: my pleasure. Please mark the answer as accepted (and do this for the other questions you asked too), this will encourage people to help you more.

Comment: @Henkka: there is a check mark under the number of votes left to each answer. Click it so that it becomes green.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a different one:

The site was (accidentally) accessible for everyone. So the update script was startet multiple times. That caused race conditions that threw errors like this.

-> Be sure that the site gets accessed only once, until every script finished!